# filedialog CheckPathExists property in c#

Tags: c#

What does the `CheckPathExists` property of the `OpenFileDialog` class do in C#? When I set it to false, it still checks the path.

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog.CheckPathExits = false;
```

Comment: Posting a question with clear explanation and code will get the quick and correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [document page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.checkpathexists.aspx) for that property, it's kind of misnamed.  It doesn't mean whether the class checks if a path exists.  It only means whether it warns the user that the path doesn't exist.

Comment: I mean it still shows the warning message whether it is false or true

Answer (score 0):

There are two similar properties: `CheckPathExists` and `CheckFileExists`.

But notice that if the path doesn't exist, then the file can't exist either. So if you want to be able to type in anything and have it accepted, then you need to set both properties to false.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous answers, this property won't help you. If you want to set value if a path does not exist, you can use something like this:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if(!Directory.Exists(path)) //Where path may be the string input of the path
{
  openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\"; 
 //Just an example, you can set a default path here
}
```